# Best way to jump to the nth string block?

Tags: navigation

Given a line like this:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="update general">
```

What is the best way to jump directly to the `value` string block?

Usually I’d use `ci"` to when there is only one string in the line. But in cases with multiple strings, Im looking for a quicker way to jump to the nth `" "` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other text objects, `i"` takes a count: `c2i"`, but the general expectation is for text objects to expand *both ways*, so it doesn't really help.

You could count your way to the relevant quote:

```
5f"
```

and then do your edit:

```
ci"
```

Or you could simply search for `up` in `update`:

```
/up<CR>
```

and then do your edit:

```
ci"
```

FWIW, I am *very* partial to the "search" method, which is my default navigation method.

Alternatively, you could look around for a plugin that provides exactly what you are looking for, in this case an XML attribute text object. Like [this one](https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-textobj-xmlattr) (untested).

Comment: I agree. I use search quite a lot too so this is the right solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would do: `5f"ci"`

Where `5f"` goes to the fifth quote (star for the third string).

For the nth string it would be: 2*n-1 instead of 5.

Comment: With (n-1)*2+1 being 2n-1 :-) Even 2n would work, as you can start from the closing quote.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably type `fvf"ci"` or `fvwwci"` (not sure how many `w`s it takes) because that’s faster for me than counting. Or even `$F"ci"`, but that’s not as general.